# Acumatica REST API INTran

Tags: rest, api, acumatica

I have a Generic Inquiry and Endpoint to get all rows and fields of INTran, which works fine.

What fields in an INTran row are it's unique keys?

I am populating a DB on a different server with this data, so I can do some detailed analysis.

I am using the LastModified field to get updates, and I need to setup my local DB keys so the correct row will be updated, and a new row will not be inserted (unless its keys are new).

I do not have login access to the Acumatica server, so I have to do this through the API.

Version 2019R1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the Acumatica website you can look up the INTran DAC (class INTran) with the `Source Code` page SM204570.

[image]

The DAC indicates primary keys are fields:

1. INTran.DocType
2. INTran.RefNbr
3. INTran.LineNbr

You can also deduce the DB type and length in the DAC attribute from the same INTran DAC.

Example DocType, PXDBString with IsFixed of length 1 maps to DB type char(1) :

```
#region DocType
public abstract class docType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<docType> { }
protected String _DocType;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = INRegister.docType.DisplayName)]
[PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true, IsKey = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(INRegister.docType))]
[INDocType.List()]
public virtual String DocType
{
    get { return this._DocType; }
    set { this._DocType = value; }
}
#endregion
```

PXDBString without IsFixed maps to `varchar` type.

PXDBString with IsUnicode maps to `nvarchar`.

PXDBInt maps to `int`.

DAC attributes should always match the DB type but DB is the final source of truth.

In DB here's how those fields are declared:

```
[DocType] [char](1) NOT NULL
[RefNbr] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL
[LineNbr] [int] NOT NULL
```

Comment: Answer shows how to determine the keys for any table, instead of simply providing the keys for the table in question. Well done.

Comment: For anyone reading this... In the API DocType is actually DocumentType, RefNbr is ReferenceNbr, and LineNbr is LineNumber. Similar translations may be necessary depending upon the table in question.

Comment: Yes the naming discrepancy is confusing, the API uses the Display Name property without the spaces instead of the field name. You have field name as DocType, display name is Document Type and API uses display name without space which yields DocumentType.